# Mixed linear programming if...then

Tags: linear-programming

I need to model the following statement:

if $\sum\limits_{i=1}^N X_i=k$ then $Y=1$ else $Y=0$

$X_i$'s are binary variables

$k$ is an integer between $0$ and $N$

$Y$ is a binary variable

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case $N$ is a constant, then add the following two inequalities to your MILP:
$$NY \leq k $$
$$N-1+Y \geq k$$

As $Y$ is a binary variable, if $k\lt N$ then $Y$ must be $0$ to fulfill both inequalities. And when $k=N$ then $Y$ must be $1$ to fulfill both inequalities

Comment: Thank you so much for your proposition. but when k=N (k<>0), with Y=0 both inequalities are true and with Y=1, the second inequality is False. Thanks again.

Comment: My apologies, I corrected the inequalities.

Comment: Thank you Maksim for your solution.

Comment: HI, Is it possible to model: if X>k then Y=0, if X<k then Y=0, if X=k then Y=1. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is $X$ a constant ?

Comment: X is a decision variable between 0 and N, Y is a binary decision variable and k is an integer (constant).

Comment: Is $X$ bounded, i.e. are there some constants $a,b$ such that $a\leq X\leq b$?

Comment: Yes, $$0\leq X\leq N$$.

Comment: added a separate answer to your 2nd Q

Answer (score 0):

To your question in the comments: $N$ positive constant, $k$ positive integer constant with $k\leq N$, $X$ decision variable with $0\leq X \leq N$.

Add 3 binary variables $r_1, r_2,r_3$ together with the following constraints:
$$ \eqalign{
kr_1 & \leq X \\
X & \leq (1-r_1)(k-1)+r_1N \\
(k+1)(1-r_2) & \leq X\\
X & \leq kr_2+(1-r_2)N\\
2r_3 & \leq r_1 +r_2 \\
r_1 +r_2 & \leq 1+ r_3 
}$$

Then $r_3 = 1$ iff $X=k$, else $r_3 = 0$

Comment: Thank you Maksim again for your response. I noticed that in case X>k or X<k it works perfectly, but when X=k, $$r_1$$ could be 0/1 and $$r_2$$ could be 0/1 and if they both are not 1 and 1 $$r_3$$  should be 0 and it is false.

Comment: Pls check again.

Comment: Yes, it works in all cases!! Thank you so much. If possible, I would like to know if you find these solution just by intuition (experience) or there is a method that helps (I am relatively new and sometimes I get stuck!) . Thkx again.